# Any alternate approximation to this method in matlab?

Tags: c, polynomial-math, curve-fitting

I am trying to convert below matlab/octave function to C(Conventional way - understand the matlab function and code it in C from scratch). It is fitting a data to a gaussian curve using polynomial fitting.

```
   function y=func(data)
   N=128;
   y1=gausswin(N,4);
   x1=[0:1/N:1-1/N]';
   P=polyfit(x1,y1,12);      
   y=polyval(P,data);
```

But when I checked the functions polyfit, that seemed a lot of work as it involves lot of calls to further octave library functions. It computes a Vandermonde matrix first, then performs some QR decomposition of it, and computes norm of the vector etc...

1. What other options/processing I can utilize to have similar functionality(approximation of the actual operation happeneing above) but with some simpler curve fitting or interpolation methods.

Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: I will say only that fitting a high order polynomial curve to Gaussian data is a foolish thing to do. 12th degree is high.

Comment: @Although it is aside to my OP, why is it not useful to have higher degree polynomial curve fitted to Gaussian data?

Comment: You wrote about fitting "gaussian curve using polynomial fitting". Do you have a reason to use polynomial fitting?

Comment: If you want to fit a polynomial to a Gaussian, I recommend Taylor series expansion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the point of the practical value of fitting such a polynomial to a gaussian, you can just analyze the behavior of your code:

```
N=128;
y1=gausswin(N,4);
x1=[0:1/N:1-1/N]';
P=polyfit(x1,y1,12);
```

The output of this section will always be the same, so you can execute this in MATLAB or Octave and just extract the polynomial `P` for usage in your C code where you include it as a constant. It's less flexible than rewriting everything in C, but it's also faster.

Otherwise, you might want to take a look at [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms): BLAS defines an API for libraries used for linear algebra such as [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) (which is used by MATLAB). I suspect a lot of these libraries will implement the basic operations you need.

**Addition**:
If you have no little experience with numerical computing or just want a lot of work taken out of your hands, you might want to consider [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/).

Comment: @Egon:To the point of getting a polynomial coefficients P, you might be correct that the outputs might be constant and can be used in C as an const float array or something But  y=polyval(P,data); is not constant and implementing that in C could be tricky/tedious.

Comment: @goldenmean: I highly doubt that implementing `polyval` yourself would be tricky or tedious. In any case, should numerical problems arise, a lot of literature is available. But it will certainly be more tedious than have someone else do the work for you.

Comment: Checked both - BLAS src, and ATLAS src. Could not find curve fitting/polynomial fitting related anything.

Comment: @goldenmean: You might not find polynomial fitting inside BLAS or ATLAS directly, but you will find QR-decomposition there (which in my opinion is the hardest part). Polynomial fitting is not hard to do, you need to construct the Vandermonde matrix and solve for the coefficients. However, as I said: that first part can be pre-calculated using MATLAB, you don't even need Vandermonde matrices and QR, the only thing you have to do is write your own `polyval` alternative.

Comment: @Egon: Actually for my case. Polynomial is always constant for each call. So I stored it as floating point array constants. Now looking to convert the polyfit function from Matlab, which is not much complicated. Basically it evaluates the polynomial at those points(data point raised to the powers of x) multiplied by the coefficients. This happens for each data point in the input/vector array. So implementing that in C. Thanks for pointers and hints.

Comment: @goldenmean: indeed your polynomial is invariant, as I said in my answer. So you indeed only need `polyval` (not `polyfit` as you mentioned, but I guess you just mistyped). Polyval is quite easy to implement, if you have any numerical problems, take a look at the Horner scheme.